# How can I find the coordinates from the distance in 3D space?

Tags: math, geometry

I know the positions of the two points.

And I also know the distance from that point(See figure below).

Then how can I find the coordinates from the distance in 3D space?

I want to do this with JavaScript...

[image: graph]

Comment: Are the points collinear?

Answer (score 1):

Find distance between end points 1 and 2

```
d12 = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (z2-z1)*(z2-z1))
```

Get point coordinates using distance ratio

```
xp = x1 + (x2-x1) * d / d12
yp = y1 + (y2-y1) * d / d12
zp = z1 + (z2-z1) * d / d12
```

Comment: This is simple and easy to understand!
Thank you very much!!